# Android Fullscreen Not Working: Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to make a fullscreen activity, but it doesn't seem to work in GingerBread, here is my code

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eyes);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

}

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   }
```

In Gingerbread there is still a title.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: is there a reason you aren't setting it from the manifest?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should set the activity as full screen in the manifest.
In the desired activity, add this code

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and your onCreate should be like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

setContentView(R.layout.main);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

}
```

This might solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that you must call `requestWindowFeature` before call `setContentView`

Try this to make a full screen activity by java:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and in Manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

`requestWindowFeature` has to be called before `super.onCreate`. Like so:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eyes);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    // ...
```

If this doesn't work, move the `getWindow().setFlags(...)` call to the top as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to not setting it in your manifest, add this attribute to your  tag in the Manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    .....
>
```

And I believe you wouldn't need the if-conditions code in the `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

isn't just `android:theme ="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` both hides the titlebar and the notification area?

it equals to:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I learn this from https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid-apidemos/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java