# RuntimeException/device crash after rotate the device by using requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

Tags: java, android, crash, rotation

The following code works for 3 of 4 devices:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Means: when the user is rotating the device into landscape mode, the titlebar is getting removed and the app goes fullscreen. So far, works on almost every device, except one in my tests.

The one it doesn't work is a Galaxy S2 with 4.1 Firmware.
It just crashes by rotating the device from portrait to landscape.
Starting the app while having it in landscape mode works, also i can rotate to portrait.
But it crashes as soon as rotating back to landscape...

This is the line causing the crash:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Logcat:

```
03-20 09:56:08.193: D/AndroidRuntime(8847): Shutting down VM
03-20 09:56:08.193: W/dalvikvm(8847): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4192d2a0)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.example/de.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$PanelFeatureState.onRestoreInstanceState(PhoneWindow.java:3741)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restorePanelState(PhoneWindow.java:1890)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1841)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:972)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:944)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1145)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
03-20 09:56:08.193: E/AndroidRuntime(8847):     ... 12 more
```

Not just the app crashes, the complete device is hanging. Only way to reactivate is to hard shut down by holding power button several seconds and restart.

Does anyone got an idea why that happens and how to solve?

I tried to surround these lines with try/catch without success...

Best regards,
Juergen

Edit:

I have created a very simple new android project with the following code in the MainActivity.java:

```
package de.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            try {
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

The layout activity_main is just an empty RelativeLayout file.

The device still crashing. If i remove the first condition "if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)" the titlebar is hidden on both portrait and landscape mode and no crash on rotating the device. But looks like i am not able to get rid of the titlebar in only landscape mode...
BUG in 4.1.2? Can someone verify that with a 4.1.2 device available?

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing seems wrong, Do you kill and restart your abd ?

Comment: Ah, i forgot to mention i also tried to changed the order of super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); to get run after the requestWindowFeature. Still the same crashing issue... Looks like theres a bug in 4.1.2 ?

Comment: Sreekanthss: sorry, i don't know how to kill the app? Can you please explain that?

Comment: You need not restart PC to overcome this. Just kill the server. if 'adb kill-server' is also not working, kill the process (adb.exe) through task manager. There you go!!

Comment: which activity are you exdends?

Comment: Oh, i don't need to restart the PC. The Smartphone is hanging and needs to be hard resetted. The pc is fine - it doesn't care about the crash of the device.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener,
  OnPageChangeListener {

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12127413

Comment: Sreekanthss, that doesn't work since i need to hide the title bar only in landscape mode.

Comment: I have created a small example project with just the lines above, without any implementations or something else. Just the activity with the above lines (i can't post it here as comment due to characters limitations :( ). The same issue. If i remove the TITLE by using requestWindowFeature without checking for landscape mode, no crash occures. Only crashing if the title bar is getting rid dynamically....

Comment: use WindowCompat.FEATURE_xxx instead of Window.FEATURE_xxx

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but WindowCompat doesn't have FEATURE_NO_TITLE.

Comment: I have edited my question on the bottom and added the simple sample code which also leads to the same crash. Also added some try/catch which is not firing - the device is still crashing...